# jQuery and php. mysql error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My code loads with the following text on top of it:
"Problem with SQL: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"
Could someone help me find a solution?
Thanks

```
//jQuery
 var value = '3';        
    $.post("load.php", {number: value} ,function(data){
    $('p').append(data);
    });          
    $('p').load('load.php');

//PHP load.php
//I have the escape inside $db.
$random = $_POST['number'];
$db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <' . '$random' . 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');

$result = $db->get();       
        foreach ($result as $key => $value){ 
        echo $value['user'];
};

//Output 
Problem with SQL: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
$value['user']
```

Comment: there's simply no value in $random.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this one:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < " . $random . " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Better use double instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because single quotes does not allow PHP to expand the variable value.

So instead of this:

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <' . '$random' . 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

You might do this:

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <' . $random . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

Just remove the quotes in $random and you'll be well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already had . $random . ,but I made a typo on here. I'm just going to use Jquery to solve my problem, since I cant find the solution for this. thank you!